# Certificate error uploading python package to local Artificatory repo

Tags: python, ssh, artifactory, pypi

We have a local PyPI store on our corporate Artifactory server. I followed the steps listed in the "Set Me Up" dialog. When I issue the command: **python setup.py sdist upload -r local** as shown on the screen I get an error:

```
running sdist
running egg_info
writing srcsrv.egg-info/PKG-INFO
...
running upload
Submitting dist/mypackage-1.0.0.tar.gz to https://artifactory.corpzone.com/artifactory/api/pypi/mypackage-local
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)>
WARNING: Uploading via this command is deprecated, use twine to upload instead (https://pypi.org/p/twine/)
error: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)>
```

I'm building and running on a Mac connected by VPN to the corporate network. I entered the correct credentials into the .pypirc file as shown.  I use the same credentials I use in the browser. I tried to issue a twine command instead but this one gets 405 response.

Any ideas how to provide a private cert?

Comment: This is not an issue with pip. this is specific to setup.py / setuptools. it is not a duplicate. Please reopen